# Creating Trigger to get data from one table to another and generating a timestamp

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am trying to track Inventory where data would be entered in an Excel sheet (SQL Spreads) and then updates the SQL table and then gather the sum of that data and put it onto another table that would then generate a timestamp to when it was changed/updated/inserted.
The Pictures with highlighted columns is where I want to have the data in.

```
(TotalBinLo --> Binlocation) 
and then when Binlocation is populated (inserted/updated/deleted) generating a timestamp (MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS)
```

This is what I've come up so far.

```
---This Trigger is working when pulling data from one table into another--
    Create Trigger tr_BC_totalbinLoc
    on bincount
    After Update
    AS
    Begin
    update OnHandInv
    set OnHandInv.binlocation = bincount.totalbinlo
    from bincount
    inner join OnHandInv on bincount.partnumber = OnHandInv.PartNumber;
    End
```

---Another Trigger (Works) but enters in date for all rows. (Don't want) (only need for one column.)

```
    Create Trigger tr_totalbinLoc_OHI
    On Onhandinv 
    After Update
    AS
    Update Onhandinv
    set dateupdated = getutcdate()
    where PartNumber in (select distinct PartNumber from onhandinv)
```

[totalbinlo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGgtj.png)
[ColNeedToPopu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSZg9.png)

Comment: Why do neither of your triggers reference the `inserted` or `deleted` objects?

Comment: @LSerni Here is what I am trying to do with that data I am able to sum up.

Comment: @Larnu I can put that in my triggers. I just haven't gotten that far atm. I'm still learning, so I'm trying to do things in steps just in case if I do one thing and then brakes or trips another thing.

Comment: *"but enters in date for all rows"* Because, again, you're not referencing `inserted`/`deleted`. Of course it's going to effect *every* row; that's what you've told it to do. `{onhandinv}.PartNumber in (select distinct PartNumber from onhandinv)` is also completely pointless. This'll evaluate to TRUE unless `PartNumber` has a value of `NULL`. The clause might as well be `PartNumber IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Larnu I see, would I use the "IF THEN" clause?

Comment: `Create Trigger tr_totalbinLoc_OHI
 On Onhandinv 
 After Update, Insert, Delete 
 AS
 Update Onhandinv
 Set dateupdated = getutcdate()`

Comment: Focus on one trigger at a time - you don't have the skills to solve all your related problems in one question and SO is designed to focus on one specific question per post. And stop the laziness. You KNOW that a trigger will almost always involve referencing the inserted or deleted tables yet you intentionally avoid doing so. In the second trigger, you either join to inserted based on PartNumber (or is it "partnumber"? be CONSISTENT) or replace the actual table with inserted inside your IN clause.

Comment: That'll still update the entirity of the table `Onhandinv`... There's *still* no reference to `inserted`. I suggest reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and some tutorials first and you are clearly not familiar with them, and [so] is not a site for tutorials.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into the documents.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join the `inserted` table to `OnHandInv`. I have assumed that `PartNumber` is the primary key to join on.

You also need to remove `deleted` rows which exactly match, in other words rows where no change has actually been made.

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER tr_BC_totalbinLoc
ON bincount
AFTER UPDATE
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;

UPDATE o
SET
  binlocation = i.totalbinlo
  dateupdated = getutcdate()
FROM (
    SELECT partnumber, totalbinlo
    FROM inserted i
    EXCEPT
    SELECT partnumber, totalbinlo
    FROM deleted d
) i
INNER JOIN OnHandInv o ON i.partnumber = i.PartNumber;

GO
```

Comment: This does work, but it's still updating the whole column with the date/time when ever I do an updated/insert data into the table.

Comment: Check your join column, should it be `partnumber`? What is the primary key?

Comment: PartNumber is the PK for both tables. I will try binlocation from OnH and totalbinlo from binc and get back to you.

Comment: Sorry need to remove `deleted` rows also

Comment: I changed the join to o.Binloc and i.totalbin, but it populates the whole column of binlocation in OnHand as one record. Example: 500 in all rows, and dates are still populating the whole column as well.

Comment: No you want to join on the primary key. Please show how you are issuing this `update`

Comment: Okay, I changed it back to the PK on the joins. The query is still the same as you showed me. It runs and pulls the data from the other table like how I wanted it to; however, it seems like its putting the same date in all the rows as if its pulling data from the column and not a single row when I update one row.

Comment: That doesn't sound like it's possible if you are joining the `inserted` table properly. Please provide a [mcve] via https://dbfiddle.uk or https://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Here are what I am using for the query. (Note: I did change the column around due to want to have set different values in the other column.) Let me know if you can't see the pictures. [https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xnza.png] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJw6F.png] [https://i.stack.imgur.com/uklUj.png]

Comment: `from bincount as i` should be `from inserted as i`. Don't complain it doesn't work if you don't copy my code correctly or understand how it works. And really I wanted a dbfiddle, but I can see the mistake anyway

Comment: Apologies if it seems like I'm complaining. I thought I was just showing you my results when running it or trying to troubleshoot on my end. Going back to your code, I just changed where I wanted the results to be.  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbOga.png]   [https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICPni.png]